# missing required parameters for route 5.6

Tags: laravel

my PostCOntroller

```
 class PostController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    $posts = post::all();
    return view('posts.index',['p'=>$posts]);
}

public function show(post $post)
{
    return view('posts.show', ['x'=>$post]);
}
```

master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "/css/bootstrap.css">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
    <center><h1>POST<h1></center>
    @yield('body')

</div>
```

index.blade.php

```
@extends('posts.master')

@section('body')
  @foreach($p as $post)
  <div class="card mt-2">
  <a href = "{{ route('hello.show'),$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a>
  </div>
 @endforeach
@endsection
```

show.blade.php

```
@extends('posts.master')

@section('body')

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
     <h3>{{$x->title}}</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="card-body">
     <h3>{{$x->content}}</h3>
  </div>

</div>

@endsection
```

web.php

```
Route::resource('hello','PostController');
```

php artisan route:list

```
 GET|HEAD  | hello              | hello.index   | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@index   | web          |
 POST      | hello              | hello.store App\Http\Controllers\PostController@store   | web          |
 GET|HEAD  | hello/create       | hello.create  | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@create  | web          |
 GET|HEAD  | hello/{hello}      | hello.show    | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@show    | web
```

in many cases i have seen the above to given as solution.. 
if i go to  link -- 127.0.0.1:8000/hello/2  then it show me the data ..it means the hello.show page is alright... the index page is showing error? what i am doing wrong?

i have tried

```
 <a href = "{{"route('hello.show'), [$post->id]"}}
 <a href = "{{"route('hello.show'), ['id'=>$post->id]"}}
 <a href = "{{"route('hello.show'), auth()->post->id]"}}
```

nothing works

the error

```
  public static function forMissingParameters($route)
{
    return new static("Missing required parameters for [Route: {$route- 
    >getName()}] [URI: {$route->uri()}].");
}

Missing required parameters for [Route: hello.show] [URI: hello/{hello}]. 
(View: F:\xampp\htdocs\sample for Laravel - 
Copy\resources\views\posts\index.blade.php
```

Comment: if you get any error please share ?

Comment: "Missing required parameters for [Route: {$route->getName()}] [URI: {$route->uri()}].");

Comment: Missing required parameters for [Route: hello.show] [URI: hello/{hello}]. (View: F:\xampp\htdocs\sample for Laravel - Copy\resources\views\posts\index.blade.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put param inside route function

```
   <a href = "{{ route('hello.show',$post->id)}}">{{$post->title}}</a>
```